# Overriding the default class attribute using django-crispy-forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I am currently learning how to use django crispy forms and can't figure out this issue. I am using it alongside bootstrap5.

I have the following form :

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta : 
        model = Comments
        fields = ["comment_content"]
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_show_labels = False
        self.fields['comment_content'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'comment here...'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            "comment_content",
        )
        self.helper.layout.append(Submit("post_comment", "Post comment",css_class="btn btn-outline-primary"))
```

The issue is with the last line : instead of replacing the default class (btn btn-primary) by the value of css_class,it simply adds this value afterwards so the resulting html is the following :

```
<input type="submit" name="post_comment" value="Post comment" class="btn btn-primary btn-outline-primary" id="submit-id-post_comment">
```

How do I make it so the resulting class is "btn btn-outline-primary" and not "btn btn-primary btn-outline-primary"?

Comment: Can you please try `self.helper.layout.append(Submit("post_comment", "Post comment", css_class="btn btn-outlined-primary"))` instead?

Comment: @SunderamDubey The issue is unfortunately still the same. The resulting html : ```<input type="submit" name="post_comment" value="Post comment" class="btn btn-primary btn btn-outlined-primary" id="submit-id-post_comment">```

Comment: Try to pass it as a list not string so: `self.helper.layout.append(
    Submit(
        "post_comment",
        "Post comment",
        css_class=["btn", "btn-outlined-primary"]
    )
)`

Comment: @SunderamDubey Same issue still, it just passes the list after btn btn-primary

Comment: But from where this `btn btn-primary` comes?

Comment: Ok I have found a fix, I will be updating my own post with the answer if it interests you !

Comment: You can provide your own Answer to the question if you found Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After analyzing the source code of the `crispy-form` layout with `bootstrap5`(exacttly Submit element), it seems like default css class is `btn btn-primary` (from source code):

```py
class Submit(BaseInput):  
    # ...
    input_type = "submit"
    field_classes = "btn btn-primary"
```

So you can modify your code little bit as below:

```py
    # ...
    self.helper.layout = Layout(
            "comment_content",
    )
    _submit = Submit("post_comment", "Post comment")
    _submit.field_classes = 'btn btn-outlined-primary '
    self.helper.layout.append(_submit)
```

Answer (score 2):

Reading the Submit class documentation (https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_layout.html#layout.Submit), we see :

> ## css_classstr, optional
>
> Additional CSS classes to be applied to the input. By default None

This means that the string provided to css_class won't override the default value, it will simply add to it.

To find the default value, we need to look at the source code for the Submit class (https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/layout.html) we see the following :

```
class Submit(BaseInput):
    input_type = "submit"
    field_classes = "btn btn-primary"
```

We can then create custom buttons by replicating the same code structure :

```
class CustomSubmit(BaseInput):
    input_type = "submit"
    field_classes = "btn btn-outline-primary"
```

I was then able to fix the problematic line as such :
`self.helper.layout.append(CustomSubmit("post_comment", "Post comment",))`

The resulting html now corresponding to the bootstrap outlined class :
`<input type="submit" name="post_comment" value="Outlined comment button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="submit-id-post_comment">`